# python3 bytes replace %3D by = in the end of file as fast as it possible

Tags: python, parsing, urllib, urldecode

I have a bytes object which is actually the file in the format of `dataurl`. It is about 500 KB.

I need to drop 37 bytes of header (I made it using a slice) and replace `%3D` by `=` at the end of the file (this sequence can be found 0-2 times).

`Urllib.parse` changes all entries in the object.

Is there a beautiful way to process this object?

```
    content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
    post_body = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
    print(len(post_body))
    with open("1111", "wb") as fd:
        fd.write(post_body)

    post_body = post_body[37:len(post_body)]

    with open("decoded.png", "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(base64.decodebytes(post_body))
```

In the last line, I have a problem.

`=` characters might be added to make the last block contain four base64 characters. But in the post request, I have `%3D` instead of `=`.

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried. Also try to give a minimal reproducible example. I'd recommend reading SO's [How to Ask Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I used decoding before parsing url. This was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to "unquote" the url escaped (`%xx`) symbols.

Python has a function for this, in python2.7 it is [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote), in python3 it is [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote). Sample usage would be:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

post_body = unquote(post_body[37:])
  # my_list[i:] is short for my_list[i:len(my_list)]
```

However, I don't know if you may only want to apply it to the last bytes, or only apply if the bytes end with `%3D`... for which you can use `.endswith()` that works for strings and bytes the same:

```
my_bytes.endswith('%3D')
```